# Polite way of asking for response as soon as possible

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, politeness

> As much this is but a straightforward question,
>   it will be a pleasure to be answered as soon as possible.

I am trying to say that since the question is simple enough I wish to get answered as quickly as possible. First, is this sentence grammatically correct? Second, can you suggest a "native" way to ask an urgent response with politeness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formulation you quoted is not clear - the problem is not in the grammar of if, but in the misused vocab. Your formulation where you explained what you meant:

> since the question is simple enough I wish to get answered as quickly as possible

while rather blunt and not exactly polite is far easier to understand.

It is not really a matter of language, but I don't think that there is a polite way to say: *This is an easy question, so the answer should not take too long.* The first part makes it impolite, because you are assuming what is easy/difficult for the person who has to answer and what's more that they should make your question a priority.

To be polite you can omit the first part and **nicely ask** for a quick response. For example:

> I would really appreciate a quick (an urgent) response.

Another way is to state that you are in a hurry for some reason (specified or unspecified) a  for example:

> This matter is urgent for me (because...), can you please respond quickly?

Don't forget that a *thank you* goes a long way.

You might also find [these options](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/how-to-thank-someone-for-a-quick-reply) from Merriam-Webster useful.

Answer (score 0):

The most polite way is to not actually directly ask for a prompt response, rather you thank them for replying promptly, which implies they should reply quickly.

Example:

> I have a question about [...]
>
> [...].
>   **I appreciate your prompt response.**
>
> Sincerely,
>
> narusawa

Where [...] is the body of your question.

Comment: I would appreciate a prompt response.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think that's as polite - it's more aggressive.